# Read the input xml data from HDFS using scala

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to parse the Xml file using Xml load in Scala.
But this program is not able to read the input data from HDFS.
It can able to read only from local file system.

Can some one please help me in how to read input data from HDFS.

Tried the below program:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

object ProcessxmlInputFiles {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Parse XML Data").setMaster("local[*]"))
    val rawRDD = xml.XML.load(args(0))
    rawRDD.child.foreach { x =>
        var dateTime = StringBuilder.newBuilder
        x.child.foreach { x =>
          if ("header".equals(x.label)) {
            dateTime.append(x.child(1).attribute("dateTime").get.toString())
          }
          ...
         }
         ...
       }
         ...
       sc.stop
      }
 }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is your input as args ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use databricks lib for [xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml)

```
//imports
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType};

/define schema for xml
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("_id", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("column1", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("column2", StringType, nullable = true)))

//read xml file
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "item")
    .schema(customSchema)
    .load("file.xml") //You can provide local file "file:///<path to your xml>" for hdfs "hdfs://<path to file>"

//write the result
val selectedData = df.select("column1", "_id")
selectedData.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rootTag", "items")
    .option("rowTag", "item")
    .save("newfile.xml")
```

Comment: Hi Faig,Thanks for your response.Here I don't want to use Dataframe.

Comment: I want to process it using XML loader only.I have the logic ready but only concern is it is not taking data from HDFS.Is there any way to read the data from HDFS using xml loader

Comment: Depending on file size approach can vary.